# Adding a custom role prefix to Grails with Spring Security

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

I am building an application which needs some roles/authorities starting with FN_ instead of ROLE_ (the Grails Spring Security plugin 2.0 only accepts ROLE_ prefixed authority names by default).

I have registered a role voter for this prefix in grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy like this:

```
  limesPermissionVoter(org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter) {
    rolePrefix = 'FN'
  }
```

I have customized the voter list in Config.groovy:

```
grails {
  plugin {
    springsecurity {
      voterNames = [
        'authenticatedVoter', 
        'roleVoter', 
        'limesPermissionVoter',
        'webExpressionVoter'
      ]
...
```

As I understand, this should be enough to use my prefixed authorities as annotations (like FN_FUNCTION1) to work.

However, when I annotate a controller (@Secured['FN_FUNCTION1']), I get a SpelEvaluationException on WebExpressionRoot jut like without the custom voter.

The new voter list seems to be processed since it fails if I remove the bean definition from resources.groovy.

What am I missing here?

One of the main problems seems to be that my FN authority strings get parsed into SpelExpresssions and as such the webExpressionVoter wants to vote on them. How do I get my FN attributes parsed as proper ConfigAttributes from which webExpressionVoter abstains?

If I use "hasRole('FN_FUNCTION1')" in place of "FN_FUNCTION1", everything works properly (as expected, since this is a proper EL expression) but I would prefer if I didn't need to write expressions for simple checks like this.
(NOTE: if I use expressions, I can omit limesPermissionVoter completely from the config since in this case we can allow webExpressionVoter to vote on these config attributes)

Comment: It says in [the documentation for the plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/domainClasses.html#authorityClass) that _"...role names must start with "ROLE". This is configurable in Spring Security, but not in the plugin."_

Comment: @Tim: The documentation may be incorrect in this case, since - in theory - you can easily override the default 'roleVoter' bean in the Spring bean config with a bean that accepts a different prefix. However, I want to leave roleVoter functional, this is why I add limesPermissionVoter after roleVoter in the voter list.

Comment: @Tim: This tells how to change from the default ROLE_ prefix to something else: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.html

Comment: Yeah, as it says, it's configurable in Spring Security